# Replace string in multiple columns in a csv

Tags: csv, awk, sed

Consider the sample below:

```
BRANCH|TXN_ID|CUSTOMER|PROCESS_DATE|VALUE_DATE|AMOUNT|UPLOAD_DATE|NARRATIVE
1|23234|12343|20141030|20141030|2000|20141030|TEST
1|23234|12343|20141030|20141030|2000|20141030|TEST
1|23234|12343|20141030|20141030|2000|20141030|TEST
1|23234|12343|20141030|20141030|2000|20141030|TEST
1|23234|12343|20141030|20141030|2000|20141030|TEST
1|23234|12343|20141030|20141030|2000|20141030|TEST
1|23234|12343|20141030|20141030|2000|20141030|TEST
```

If I use `sed 's/20141030/20141029/g'`, it will replace all instances of `20141030`, including UPLOAD_DATE, which is not what I want.

From the net, the awk examples am getting only replace one instance of the string. I need to replace all instances in one go

So my question is, how can I replace the contents of column 4 and 5 (process date and value date) using a unix script while maintaining the format of the file? The result will be written into a new file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{sub(20141030,"20141029",$4); sub(20141030,"20141029",$5); print}' inputFile
```

Gives output as

```
BRANCH|TXN_ID|CUSTOMER|PROCESS_DATE|VALUE_DATE|AMOUNT|UPLOAD_DATE|NARRATIVE
1|23234|12343|20141029|20141029|2000|20141030|TEST
1|23234|12343|20141029|20141029|2000|20141030|TEST
1|23234|12343|20141029|20141029|2000|20141030|TEST
1|23234|12343|20141029|20141029|2000|20141030|TEST
1|23234|12343|20141029|20141029|2000|20141030|TEST
1|23234|12343|20141029|20141029|2000|20141030|TEST
1|23234|12343|20141029|20141029|2000|20141030|TEST
```

Comment: @TomFenech. I was just to post a comment about FS/OFS my self.  You should not change a code for a user, but post a comment, and the user could then change it if i like to do it.

Comment: @Jotne for a major edit I agree, although in this case the changes are largely cosmetic. You or the OP are welcome to roll back the edit if you disagree with it.

Comment: @Jotne it is completely fine to edit someone's answer if it improves it like now. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Comment: @TomFenech I do agree with you in some case, but posting a comment is better, since then the poster may learn some and he/she may remove some bad habits.

Comment: No problem. @Jotne I appreciate that it's a grey area. I tried to leave a helpful edit message for that reason :)

Comment: @TomFenech No problem, we are all here to help :)

Answer (score 1):

nu11p01n73Rs answer is definitely the best solution for this specific problem but I though i would add a more general approach that could work for lots of fields.

Just add all the fields you want to change to the start of the split statement.

```
awk -F"|" -vOFS="|" '{split("4 5",A," ");for(i in A)sub(20141030,"20141029",$A[i])}1' file
```

Actually this would be more efficient.

```
  awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|";split("4 5",A," ")}{for(i in A)sub(20141030,"20141029",$A[i])}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/^\([0-9]*|\)\{3\}\)20141030/\120141029/' YourFile
```

Using sed (posix version so us `--posix` on GNU sed especially with the `|` inside)